# Rust: not found in this scope

Tags: rust

пытаюсь разобрать с вызовом кода с `c/c++` в Rust.
есть вот такой код на Rust:

```
#[cfg(all(target_arch = "x86"))]
#[link(name="lib")]
extern {
    fn get_int() -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}",unsafe{get_int()});
}
```

и такой на c++

```
int get_int(){
    return 10;
}
```

заголовочный файл:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) int get_int();
```

CMake файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project(lib)

file(GLOB CPPS "src/*.cpp")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${CPPS})
```

при компиляции выдаёт ошибку

> error[E0425]: cannot find function `get_int` in this scope

в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Опишите что вы хотите сделать. (В вопросе)

Comment: А как либа из С подключается к проекту на Rust? Есть build.rs с указанием, где и как искать либу?

Comment: @snuk182 нет... а что писать в build.rs что бы он нашёл библиотеку?

Comment: Если функция на языке С++, то ее имя будет совсем не `get_int`. На сколько я знаю, раст не поддерживает ABI C++, так что вам придется оборачивать свою функцию в C обертку.

Comment: А что если собрать функцию с `extern "C"`?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проект собирается на 64-битной системе, так что в cfg должно быть не `"x86"`, а `"x86_64"`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_arch - вот тут сейчас задокументирован список возможных значений.

Comment: в таком случае выдаёт ошибку линковки.

Comment: Тогда информации мало. Обнови вопрос, что бы проект был весь целиком.

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Comment: А какую ошибку линковки он выдаёт с x86_64?

Comment: @Tanriol вот https://pastebin.com/Cwz592aF

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить аттрибут `#[no_mangle]` к обьявлению функции. Ну и с x86_64 попробовать, как выше написали.

Comment: нет не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Уравнение с многими неизвестными. Допустим, сам код Си собирается и корректен, тогда есть как минимум два варианта:

- собрать статическую либу отдельно, в Rust проект [добавить build.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) с указанием линкеру, что и откуда влинковывать:

```rust
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static={}", lib_name);
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", path_to_lib);
```

- воспользоваться [специально обученой библиотекой сишных сборок](https://crates.io/crates/cc) и собирать либу вместе с Rust. Там тоже build.rs, но сборка и поиск либы автоматизированы.

Comment: библиотека не собирается. https://pastebin.com/BMTsm3Xy

Comment: первый способ сработал под лунуксом на винде выдаёт ошибку link.exe failed: exit code: 1120

Comment: попробуй `cc` более старой версии. у меня 1.0.25 работала точно.

Comment: Поддерживаю предложение воспользоваться крейтом `cc`, предварительно обновив версию Rust (судя по приведённой ошибке, у автора вопроса 1.26 или младше, нынешние версии `cc` хотят как минимум 1.30, если не больше).